# Debezium offset kafka topic is empty when using KafkaOffsetBackingStore

Tags: java, sql-server, apache-kafka, debezium

I try to use the KafkaOffsetBackingStore with the embedded debezium enginge. However theopic t used in the "offset.storage.topic" configuration (debezium.legacy-datasource.offset) remains empty when a change is made in the source database.

Here is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class DebeziumConfig {

    private final LegacyDataSourceProperties legacyDataSourceProperties;

    @Bean
    public io.debezium.config.Configuration legacyDatasourceConnector() {
        return io.debezium.config.Configuration.create()
                .with("name", "legacy-datasource-sqlserver-connector")
                .with("connector.class", "io.debezium.connector.sqlserver.SqlServerConnector")
                .with("offset.storage", "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.KafkaOffsetBackingStore")
                .with("offset.storage.topic", "debezium.legacy-datasource.offset")
                .with("offset.storage.partitions", 1)
                .with("offset.storage.replication.factor", 1)
                .with("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
                .with("database.hostname", legacyDataSourceProperties.getHost())
                .with("database.port", legacyDataSourceProperties.getPort())
                .with("database.user", legacyDataSourceProperties.getUsername())
                .with("database.password", legacyDataSourceProperties.getPassword())
                .with("database.names", legacyDataSourceProperties.getDbname())
                .with("database.trustServerCertificate", true)
                .with("topic.prefix", "debezium.legacy-datasource")
                .with("include.schema.changes", "false") // Schema changes are skipped
                .with("database.include.list", legacyDataSourceProperties.getDbname()) // List of watched databases
                .with("table.include.list", "dbo.ARFOLYAM") // List of watched tables
                .with("schema.history.internal.kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
                .with("schema.history.internal.kafka.topic", "debezium.legacy-datasource.schema-history")
                .with("snapshot.mode", "schema_only") // Initial change (which includes every row in a table) is skipped
                .build();
    }
}
```

My expectation would be that this topic should be populated once a change occurs in the source database. Without this, I can't keep track of changes which happened when my service was down.

I tried debugging the KafkaOffsetBackingStore.class, but did not find anything.
When using FileOffsetBackingStore everything works as expected.